# TCP packets recieved on interface but not by Ruby TCPServer

Tags: ruby, tcpserver

I have a Ruby TCPServer that does not recieve TCP packets intermittently. Note the below is run inside another `threads << Thread.new do` as I have multiple TCP post listeners.

```
server = TCPServer.new(7207)
Thread.start(server.accept) do |client|
  # process packet, send to AWS SQS
  raw = ""
  while (line = client.gets)
    raw += line
  end
  sender = client.peeraddr
  text = raw.unpack1("H*")
  message_body = { payload: text, rx_at: Time.current, sender:}
  puts "#{Time.current} : --- New uplink #{message_body}"
  # send message to AWS SQS
  client.close
end
```

I see the packets in tcpdump / wireshark but not on my TCPServer. I have a pcap file available:
https://www.dropbox.com/s/7m3hr1b7065tenx/tcp.pcap?dl=0
Example lost packets occurred on:
ip 10.0.225.43 at 27/07/2022 20:56:57 and 27/07/2022 20:39:31

Comment: I note that the missed packets only have 5 frames whereas successful ones tend to have 9 but i am unsure of the relevance

Comment: 1) Writing your own web server is generally a bad idea. Why don't you use something battle-tested like Thin, Puma, or Unicorn, or even Webrick if you don't need threaded or evented processes? 2) If there's relevant data, post it in your question; external file links are not acceptable. 3) Frame size might be related to MTU, and should be negotiated or managed between client and server, which is yet another reason not to roll your own.

Comment: Hi, the PCAP is a binary file so not easily pasted. I am not writing a web server as such, these are devices using the TCP protocol to send byte data. I assume Thin, Puma or Uniforn all work on HTTP application layer, whereas my device cannot tolerate the overhead of HTTP

Comment: I did wonder if nginx /Puma can listen on a TCP socket and proxy the network traffic to a ruby app?

Answer (score 0):

Apologies after checking Wireshark this looks like a network problem not a Ruby / dev problem. The device was not sending FIN frames so the network stack was not publishing the packet up to my app.